# CSLA SerializationException on BeginEdit when using LazyGetPropertyAsync

Tags: .net, asynchronous, serialization, business-objects, csla

Having a problem when using LazyGetPropertyAsync on a business object, I've put some code examples to show the basic structure of this issue. As soon as I call BeginEdit (After a fetch) I am getting the following SerializationException.

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Type
>   'Csla.PropertyInfo`1[[MyApp.ChildList, MyApp, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' in Assembly 'Csla,
>   Version=4.6.603.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=93be5fdc093e4c30'
>   is not marked as serializable.'

This does not happen if I replace LazyGetPropertyAsync with LazyGetProperty and then use the syncronhous method instead of the async. I also tried using LazyGetPropertyAsync< ChildList> but I still get the exception.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
    [Serializable]
    public class MyObject : BusinessBase<MyObject>
    {
         //readonly backing field here
         public ChildList Child
         {
             get
             {
                 return LazyGetPropertyAsync(ChildProperty, ChildList.FetchAsync());
             }
         }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class ChildList : ReadOnlyListBase<ChildList, ChildObject>
    {
          public static ChildList Fetch()
          {
               //fetch here
          }

          public static async Task<ChildList> FetchAsync()
          {
               //fetch here
          }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class ChildObject : ReadOnlyBase<ChildObject>
    {
         //some stuff here
    }
```

Comment: Check your properties. Did you put attribute to any of the as `NonSerializable`.
P.S. Yea I know it's old, but it might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a bug in the Csla framework, which is storing the `Task<T>` into the FieldManager, instead of the result of awaiting that `Task<T>`.

Comment: Cheers for the response. I've checked the definition of the function for the async method:

`protected P LazyGetPropertyAsync<P>(PropertyInfo<P> property, Task<P> factory);`

It definitely should return a task, so what I've got is correct. Trying to return a function will result in an error because it isn't a delegate type.

The non-async equivalent requires a Func<T>, so that might be where the confusion has arisen.

Comment: @MattConway So it is; I suspect this is a bug in the framework then.